# how to list emmet commands on top of autosuggestion list

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to display emmet commands or other snippets on top of the list of autosuggested completions?

My main problem is that in an .html file let's say I paste some Lorem Ipsum text, my autosuggestion list gets "polluted" by these random works and working with html snippets becomes an ordeal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't include emmmet commands in the suggestion list, but try setting `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"` to display the snippets first.

You may also want to try `"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false` to disable some of the suggestion "pollution" you are seeing

Comment: Thank you, with `editor.snippetSuggestions: top` it became much more usable!! Basically this was my ideal behavior. I didn't change the `wordBasedSuggestions` setting because I think I'll need this functionality later on.